# Wrote a very simple HTTP server(JAVA), its giving strange results, while writing to browser?

Tags: java, sockets, http, server

Just as a curiosity I was writing a Test HTTP server, which would accept request from a browser app and send it a response, based on simple Server Socket model.

I have two methods for sending a HTTP method: `sendHttpResponse1()` & `sendHttpResponse2()`, which basically read from a file: `httpResponse.txt` (which contains HTTP response headers + HTML code, see below file content)
and send response to client via socket connections.

I use either of the methods in my main Method, while sending response.

Both methods do not behave the way I expect.

My code is :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestHttpServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ServerSocket sruSoc = new ServerSocket(8333);


                Socket clientConnection = sruSoc.accept();
                InputStream is = clientConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr, 100);

                while((message=br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(message);
                if(message.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Request received");

            sendHttpResponse2(clientConnection);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }



private static void sendHttpResponse1(Socket clientConnection)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
    File file = new File("httpResponse.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buff = new byte[50];
    System.out.println("\nThis is what client will see");
    System.out.println();
    while(fis.read(buff)!=-1){
        String lineB = new String(buff);
        pw.write(lineB);
        System.out.println(lineB);
    }
    fis.close();
    pw.close();
}

private static void sendHttpResponse2(Socket clientConnection)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
    File file = new File("resources/httpResponse/httpResponse.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    System.out.println("\nThis is what client will see");
    System.out.println();
    String line=null;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
    pw.write(line);
    System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    //pw.flush();
    pw.close(); 
}

}
```

File :httpResponse.txt

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Test/0.1 (Java)
Content-Type: text/html;
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-5, unicode-1-1;q=0.8
Accept-Ranges: none
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <b>Hello World</b>, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

Output of `sendHttpResponse1()`:

```
Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document. is a very si
```

Output of `sendHttpResponse2()`:

No response, empty browser.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong in the above two methods?
I did a lot of head breaking, but it seems I am doing some silly mistake, which is not giving me the expected output.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any one please , help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer: basics :
In sendHttpResponse2:
the line that was causing the issue was : byte[] buff = new byte[50];
fixed size byte array , and hence in correct outputs.

In sendHttpResponse2:
It should be println rather than write() .